# Why does my child component loses its props after an API call returns

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component which, along with some other children, renders a child component called `PaymentForm`.

I am passing a callback function called `paymentSucceeded` to the child via props like so:

```
// this is in the render method of the parent
<PaymentForm
  paymentSucceeded={ () => {
    this._postJob()
}}/>
```

The `PaymentForm` then uses the Stripe API to perform a credit card transaction and upon successful completion should call the callback `paymentSucceeded`. However, at the time when the payment was successfully executed, `this.props` of the `PaymentForm` is `undefined` and I have no clue why.

```
export default class PaymentForm extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    console.log('PaymentForm - constructor - props: ', props) // (1)
  }

  _receiveCreditCardInfo(creditCardDetails) {
    const creditCardInfo = {creditCardInfo: creditCardDetails}
    console.log('PaymentForm - _receiveCreditCardInfo - props: ', this.props) // (2)

    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }),
      body: JSON.stringify(creditCardInfo)
    }).then( (data) => {
      this.props.paymentSucceeded() // this doesn't work bc this.props is undefined
    }).catch( (error) => {
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <StripeCheckout
        token={this._receiveCreditCardInfo}
        stripeKey={STRIPE_TEST_API_KEY} />
    )
  }
}
```

The first log `(1)` properly prints the `props` object along with the function `paymentSucceeded`, however the second log `(2)` prints `undefined` for the props. Consequently, I get the error message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property `paymentSucceeded` of `undefined`

Comment: what happens if you bind `_receiveCreditCardInfo` to instances instead of declaring it as a class method:  `_receiveCreditCardInfo = (creditCardDetails) => { /* ... */ };` ?

Comment: not _quite_ sure what you mean! I can redeclare `_receiveCreditCardInfo` as you suggested: `const _receiveCreditCardInfo = (creditCardDetails) => { ... }`. should I do that inside the scope of the class `PaymentForm`? should I leave the rest as is? (sry I don't have a lot of experience with js)

Comment: ha I actually solved it, your hint helped me!

Comment: @DanO just add your comment as an answer and I'll accept so you get your points! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue by changing the `render` method of `PaymentForm` to the following:

```
return (
  <StripeCheckout
    token={ () => { this._receiveCreditCardInfo() }}
    stripeKey={STRIPE_TEST_API_KEY} />
)
```